# Occur Fatal Error when trying to run command 'flutter create xxx;cd xxx;flutter run'

Tags: flutter, arm64, wayland

I have 'rock5b SBC' on arm64 arch, and installed 'debian11' and 'flutter'.

% uname -a

```
Linux rock-5b 5.10.110-34-rockchip-gca15bbe36e6c #rockchip SMP Wed Dec 7 06:54:05 UTC 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

(% flutter channel stable) # already changed stable

% flutter --version

```
Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter
Framework • revision 135454af32 (4 days ago) • 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
Engine • revision 3316dd8728
Tools • Dart 2.18.6 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

% flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 5.10.110-34-rockchip-gca15bbe36e6c, locale
    ja_JP.UTF-8)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

% flutter create sample

% cd sample

% flutter run

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
Building Linux application...  
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: rockchip
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: rockchip
[FATAL:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl_delegate.cc(57)] Check failed: gl_version_string. The GL proc resolver's glGetString(GL_VERSION) failed
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly, or never started.
Error launching application on Linux.
```

hope it runs fine on linux.

Comment: rock5bにopenGL ESもどきのドライバを追加したら進展がありました。

Comment: ただ、まだflutter runをおこなうと、WARNING **: 21:07:27.876: Failed to start Flutter renderer: 指定された RGBA ピクセルフォーマットの利用可能な設定はありません と表示されます。まっさらなwindowが表示されるのですが、かなりの進展です。